# Comprehensive Theming Failed - AttributeError: Namespace '__anon_0x7f3dc61e5950' has no member 'stanford_theme_enabled'

Tags: django, bitnami, openedx

I am new to OpenEdx and I have setup my system using the Bitnami stack. But I cant seem to be able to setup custom comprehensive theming. LMS throws Internal Server Error. I have below my tailed server log

Here's what I have done so far.

1. Downloaded theme from - https://themex.io/
2. Set COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIR = "/path-to-theme"
3. Ran SERVICE_VARIANT=lms ./bin/paver.edxapp update_assets lms --settings=aws and this finished successfully
4. Launch LMS, 500 Internal Server Error

What am I doing wrong?

```
[Mon Sep 12 05:10:14.551555 2016] [:error] [pid 31981] [remote 127.0.0.1:512]     runtime._include_file(context, (static.get_themed_template_path(relative_path='theme-header.html', default_path='navigation.html')), _template_uri)
[Mon Sep 12 05:10:14.551570 2016] [:error] [pid 31981] [remote 127.0.0.1:512]   File "/home/harrypalace/manjaro_vlp/apps/edx/edx-platform/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 752, in _include_file
[Mon Sep 12 05:10:14.551592 2016] [:error] [pid 31981] [remote 127.0.0.1:512]     callable_(ctx, **_kwargs_for_include(callable_, context._data, **kwargs))
[Mon Sep 12 05:10:14.551607 2016] [:error] [pid 31981] [remote 127.0.0.1:512]   File "/home/harrypalace/manjaro_vlp/.tmp/mako_lms/a2ab4a911ea1f0731584a3dbc36a191f/navigation.html.py", line 48, in render_body
[Mon Sep 12 05:10:14.551630 2016] [:error] [pid 31981] [remote 127.0.0.1:512]     _mako_get_namespace(context, '__anon_0x7f3dc61e5950')._populate(_import_ns, [u'login_query', u'stanford_theme_enabled'])
[Mon Sep 12 05:10:14.551645 2016] [:error] [pid 31981] [remote 127.0.0.1:512]   File "/home/harrypalace/manjaro_vlp/apps/edx/edx-platform/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 525, in _populate
[Mon Sep 12 05:10:14.551667 2016] [:error] [pid 31981] [remote 127.0.0.1:512]     d[ident] = getattr(self, ident)
[Mon Sep 12 05:10:14.551688 2016] [:error] [pid 31981] [remote 127.0.0.1:512]   File "/home/harrypalace/manjaro_vlp/apps/edx/edx-platform/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 625, in __getattr__
[Mon Sep 12 05:10:14.551711 2016] [:error] [pid 31981] [remote 127.0.0.1:512]     (self.name, key))
[Mon Sep 12 05:10:14.551736 2016] [:error] [pid 31981] [remote 127.0.0.1:512] AttributeError: Namespace '__anon_0x7f3dc61e5950' has no member 'stanford_theme_enabled'
```

Answer (score -2):

You should take a look at the guide below:

[How to Install a Custom Theme](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/edx/#how-to-install-a-custom-standford-theme)

It describes the process to follow in order to install a custom them on Bitnami OpenEDX.